# Does pygame allow importing external Python libraries

Tags: python, flash, pygame, game-engine, game-maker

I am developing a game for a website.  It would look somewhat similar to the image  [The layout of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iocdJ.png).

The only problem here is that this is a flash game. And the game logic is already hardcoded into the source code.

I need to use external python library like(https://github.com/franciscogarate/pyliferisk). The user input will be passed to these python library which will then pass the output to the game.

According to my research, It is not possible to use external python library while using ActionScript3 to make flash games.GameMaker wont allow me to import external libraries And i have also read about Pygame(The gaming library for python). But i am not sure if we can import external libraries along with pygame.

So, My questions are:-

1) Can we import external python libraries like (https://github.com/franciscogarate/pyliferisk) along with Pygame.

2) Are there any Game engine like Game Maker which will allow me to use the external python library.

3) And since i am a novice how long would i take me to make simple point and click game like [This one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iocdJ.png) using pygame.

Disclaimer:- The image of the game has been taken from https://www.practicalmoneyskills.com/play# . The name of the game is Countdown to retirement

Comment: for first question: did you try import ? did you have problem ? next time first try, next ask.

Comment: for third question: there is no good answer. some people need short time to do game, other need few years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use as many external libraries as you want. In fact, it is common to `import` external libraries.
2. Currently, there is no GUI based software to help in making games in `pygame`. You'll have to code everything without one.
3. `Pygame` is one of the simplest libraries to use, after following some tutorials, you should be up pretty quickly.

Comment: Does that mean i can import the python library and use its functions along with pygame. Lets call the external python library 'X'. Can i pass the user input taken in the pygame and pass it to X and then get the output from X and pass it back to the game?

Comment: Yes. You can `import` any functionality from X and use it with `Pygame`.

Comment: Would it be better if i use Panda3d or pygame?

Comment: @Naveen there is no good answer what to choose `Panda3d or pygame` - some people prefer pygame other panda3d. Maybe first start doing game instead of only asking.